# The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am developing a handset application in .net framework 3.5,which is using an API service call to check the email address from website.I am using the below code to perform that,

```
using System.Net.Http;

HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient();
webClient.QueryString.Add("email", email);
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(brandEndPoint);
```

Initially i used `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient` and i got this error "`The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found`" google and fixed this with `HttpClient`.

After replacing `WebClient` with `HttpClient` i am getting this error "`The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net`".

Need help to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: @Steve: Why? HttpClient is in the System.Net.Http namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

Comment: Not for .NET 3.5. The namespace isn't available at all for 3.5

Comment: @JonSkeet too fast indeed, looking with Intellisense in LinqPAD, missing the reference and jumping to the wrong conclusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpClient` is available in .NET 4.5 or 4.0 with the [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) NuGet package. It isn't at all available for .NET 3.5.

`HttpClient` uses features like the TPL that are only available in .NET 4+.

You'll have to use either [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If you get any compilation errors, make sure you've added the proper `using` statements. These two classes are available since .NET 1.1, in the `System.dll` library and thus are always available.

Comment: May i know what is the substitute for HttpClient in .net 3.5.I am newly learning .net can you please tell me how to solve my issue.

Comment: Check the edit. You already used the proper type but forgot to use the proper namespace. Check the docs, they contain a simple but complete sample