# Compilation error in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cloud-services

After trying and browsing through a lot of answers on stack overflow, I am not able to solve my issue so I am posting the question here.

I have a azure cloud service with both web and worker roles. My compilation is successful and when I start the service locally, the service starts for debugging successfully

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

i have added the reference to this dll, have confirmed that this is getting binplaced properly but still I am getting this error every time. I cleaned the build, restarted the system and tried many suggestions posted in stackoverflow or in various blogs.

Even if I remove this line from my code, I get error in next line where I have referenced System.Web.Mvc

Any help to get past this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Add code please

Comment: What is the .NetFramework you are using? Could you please confirm the same version is used in Azure Cloud Service? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120543/the-type-or-namespace-name-http-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-net